# Dato nuevo ingresado solo se muestra al recargar la página, en caso de que datos previos ya hayan sido cargados y mostrados

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una práctica en JavaScript con eventos; tengo un formulario al que le voy ingresando datos para luego mostrarlos en un modal.

Si cargo datos en forma consecutiva y luego quiero mostrarlos, aparecen todos. Si luego de mostrarlos, agrego un nuevo dato y vuelvo a mostrar, este último no aparece: recién lo hace cuando actualizo la página.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Dejo el código que tengo hecho hasta el momento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--BOOTSTRAP V5.1-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-5 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" id="btnReserva" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalReservas">Reservas <span>0</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Compras <span>0</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Formulario</h1>
    <form id="formReserva">
      <div class="mt-5 mb-3 col-md-5">
        <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
        <label for="fecha" class="form-label">Elegí una fecha</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="hora" class="form-label">Elegí un horario</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirmar reserva</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modalReservas" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Tus reservas</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>    
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hora</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody id="bodyReservas">
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>






<!-- JS BOOTSTRAP V5.1-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- JS PROPIO-->
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
class Reserva{
    constructor(nombre, fecha, hora){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.hora = hora;
    }
}

let reservas;

let formReserva = document.getElementById('formReserva');
let bodyReservas = document.getElementById('bodyReservas');


//Consulto si hay datos almacenados en LS
 if(localStorage.getItem('reservas')){
     reservas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservas'));
 } else{
     reservas = [];
 }



//Evento para capturar datos del fomrulario
formReserva.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let nombreReserva = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    let fechaReserva = document.getElementById('fecha').value;
    let horaReserva = document.getElementById('hora').value;

    let objReserva = new Reserva(nombreReserva, fechaReserva, horaReserva);
    reservas.push(objReserva);

    localStorage.setItem('reservas', JSON.stringify(reservas));

    formReserva.reset();
})


//Evento que muestra datos ingresados en un Modal
document.getElementById('btnReserva').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    let storageReservas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservas'));

    if(bodyReservas.children.length == 0){
        storageReservas.forEach((reservaArray) => {
            bodyReservas.innerHTML += `

            <tr>
                <td>${reservaArray.nombre}</td>
                <td>${reservaArray.fecha}</td>
                <td>${reservaArray.hora}</td>
            </tr>
            `
        })
        
    }
})
```

Comment: Prueba el uso de `socket.io` te pueda servir a tu problemática.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema es que el modal ser arma al cargar la página, lo
único que hace el link a reservas es mostrar u ocultar el modal, una forma fácil de solucionarlo es quitar el preventDefault del listener del submit. De esa forma se agrega y se recarga, actualizando el modal. También agregué la funcionalidad de contar las reservas y mostrarlas en tiempo real.

HTML quedaría así: (un dato, en las rutas no debes poner ./ al inicio, no en HTML, lo harías con React)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!--BOOTSTRAP V5.1-->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-5 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link active"
                aria-current="page"
                href="#"
                id="btnReserva"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#modalReservas"
                >Reservas <span id="cantidadReservas"></span></a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Compras <span>0</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="mt-5">Formulario</h1>
      <form id="formReserva">
        <div class="mt-5 mb-3 col-md-5">
          <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
          <label for="fecha" class="form-label">Elegí una fecha</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label for="hora" class="form-label">Elegí un horario</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            Confirmar reserva
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalReservas" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Tus reservas</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                  <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                  <th scope="col">Hora</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody id="bodyReservas"></tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Cerrar
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JS BOOTSTRAP V5.1-->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- JS PROPIO-->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y el Script quedaría así:

```
class Reserva{
    constructor(nombre, fecha, hora){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.hora = hora;
    }
}

let reservas;

let formReserva = document.getElementById('formReserva');
let bodyReservas = document.getElementById('bodyReservas');
let cantidadReservas = document.getElementById('cantidadReservas') // Capturo el Span del numero


//Consulto si hay datos almacenados en LS
 if(localStorage.getItem('reservas')){
     reservas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservas'));
cantidadReservas.textContent= reservas.length  // Pongo el largo del array e  n el span
 } else{
     reservas = [];
     cantidadReservas.textContent= 0  // Pongo en cero el span si no hay reservas
 }



//Evento para capturar datos del fomrulario
formReserva.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
    let nombreReserva = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    let fechaReserva = document.getElementById('fecha').value;
    let horaReserva = document.getElementById('hora').value;

    let objReserva = new Reserva(nombreReserva, fechaReserva, horaReserva);
    reservas.push(objReserva);

    localStorage.setItem('reservas', JSON.stringify(reservas));

    formReserva.reset();
})


//Evento que muestra datos ingresados en un Modal
document.getElementById('btnReserva').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    let storageReservas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservas'));

    if(bodyReservas.children.length == 0){
        storageReservas.forEach((reservaArray) => {
            bodyReservas.innerHTML += `

            <tr>
                <td>${reservaArray.nombre}</td>
                <td>${reservaArray.fecha}</td>
                <td>${reservaArray.hora}</td>
            </tr>
            `
        })
        
    }
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Luis! Me es de gran ayuda. Agradezco también el tiempo que has tomado para proponer la solución. Saludos y felices fiestas!

Comment: Es un placer poder ayudar Matias, en esto crecemos juntos!. Felices fiestas para ti y tu gente también!